# First app published, can't get keystore for Maps/Places

Tags: android, maps, publish, sha1

I've published my first app as part of my final school project, but used the debug keystore with Android Studio. Now that I'm trying to get an SHA1 so my Google Maps will work, I'm running into this:

> C:\Users\TOUKOD>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\keytool.exe" -list -v -alias WBiAssistant -keystore "C:\Users\TOUKOD\.android\WBiAsisstant.jks" -storepass password -keypass password keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\TOUKOD\.android\WBiAsisstant.jks java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\TOUKOD\.android\WBiAsisstant.jks
>           at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:742)
>           at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:340)
>           at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:333)

To my understanding, it should work using this in the Command Prompt:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\keytool.exe" -list -v -alias WBiAssistant -keystore "C:\Users\TOUKOD\.android\WBiAsisstant.jks" -storepass password -keypass password

I've made new keystores to no avail. I've searched for hours for this same issue to prevent any repeats. I'm also having an issue with the Places API because it no longer shows local places with the browser keys I generate and regenerate. I'm at a loss, here.

Comment: For school ..... don't forget the key resources of your Professor and other TAs!

Comment: I'm using the resources they've given me. Unfortunately, it was not the best prepared curriculum, and the subject matter was not as extensive as intended, nor were there any truly experienced instructors. I've spoken to at least a few in the industry and they specifically mention this site to ask questions I can't solve and reach out to the community for assistance I can't receive at a school I'm graduating from.

Comment: Do you have this file: C:\Users\TOUKOD\.android\debug.keystore?  If so that should work.

Comment: @adavis Apologies for the delay. Yes, I use that now. Nothing shows.